# What is the mysterious black ring in this spectacular photo of London at night?

Tags: photography, space

In [this supposed night photograph of London from space](http://telegraph.co.uk/technology/picture-galleries/9202815/Andre-Kuipers-space-station-astronaut-sends-pictures-to-Earth-via-Twitter.html):

[image: photo from Telegraph]

there is a black ring just north of The O2 — see the circle in the top-right quadrant below?

[image: see the circle in the top-right quadrant?]

I can't find it on Google Maps.

Is it a real feature, something on the lens or window, or evidence that the photo is fake?

Comment: Looking at Google Maps, I'd suggest it a combination of the RIver Lea, the River Channelsea and the London Overground.

Comment: The photo is not looking straight down on London, so the image is skewed and distorted a bit.  I agree that it is the River Lea/River Channelsea combined with the Stratford train yard.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with travel.

Comment: The ancient Ford assembly plant, now inoperative, accounts for the dark caterpillar-like blob upstream.  Also Regent's Park and Hyde Park are dark.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is just an illusion nothing more.

[image: londong]

Map from [Bing maps](http://binged.it/1R0qAmA)

Comment: This is a great answer that shows personal initiative and first principles research. It uses a graphic because the satellite photo was taken over southern France whereas Google Maps looks straight down.

Comment: Wow! Amazing presentation of data. Wish I could upvote you more!

Answer (score 6):

Here's [another source for what appears to be the same photograph](http://www.esa.int/spaceinimages/Images/2012/04/London_by_night) downloadable at higher resolution.

I think it's the parking lot (and row of trees next to it) encircling a bus garage. Here is [a link to Google Earth (via Google Maps)](https://www.google.com/maps/@51.5251464,0.0011686,702m/data=!3m1!1e3) zoomed in on it.
The image is rotated relative to Google's map (north is not "straight up"), and, as someone else pointed out, the city is not seen from straight above but from an angle.

Wikimedia has [a different one from the other direction](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/London-at-night-from-air.jpg) which might lead to further insight (or intrigue).